# How do I 301 redirect /Home to root?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-301

Here is my route in Global.asax to remove /Home:

```
    routes.MapRoute("Root", "{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Well I need to setup a 301 redirect because someone linked to /Home and they're getting a 404.

So how do I setup the 301?

I checked the way the route was setting up and it is looking for a "Home" action method in the "Home" controller.

So obviously I could add:

```
public ActionResult Home() {
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.RedirectLocation = "/";
    Response.End();
    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

However, there's gotta be a better way of doing this right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to allow this URL, you can do

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "Home",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But you want redirection, and it does make most sense, so...

Another thing you can do is create another controller Redirector and an action Home.

```
public class RedirectorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("~/");
    }
}
```

Then you set the routes as:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "Home",
        new { controller = "Redirector", action = "Home"});
```

Remember to add the route at the top of your routes so that the generic routes don't match instead.

**Update:**

Another thing you can do is add this to the end of your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "{controller}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But this is not redirect still. So, can change the Redirector to be generic as...

```
public class RedirectorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Redirect(string controllerName, string actionName)
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent(actionName, controllerName);
    }
}
```

Then the route (which should be now at the bottom of all routes) will be:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "{controllerName}",
        new { controller = "Redirector", action = "Redirect", 
              controllerName = "Home", actionName = "Index" });
```

So, it'll try to redirect to the Index action of a controller with the same name as /name. Obvious limitation is the name of the action and passing parameters. You can start building on top of it.

Comment: Too funny, I was editing my "question" right as you typed this and came up with the same thing.

Comment: Any idea why links to Url.Action("Index", "Home") would now appear like: http://example.com/Home/Index?action=Index&controller=Home

Comment: If after taking the last path in the update, are you sure you added it at the very bottom?

Comment: I fixed it.  I also found that just making a link to <a href="/" without Url.Action fixed it as well.

Comment: Aha. I thought you already had that and the link your are talking about is out of your hand (like, already indexed in search engines or likely bookmarked by users or so).

Comment: Make sure to use double quotes on the controllerName var otherwise it will not build.
routes.MapRoute("Root", "{controllerName}",
        new { controller = "Redirector", action = "Redirect", 
              controllerName = "Home", actionName = "Index" });