# Redirect user to from a SEO like url to a controller action in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, routes, seo

is it possible to redirect a static seo "friendly" url address to a controller/action without loosing the original address?

For example:

- if you navigate to http://localhost/find-the-best-employees
- under the hood MVC takes you to http://localhost/Search/Employees (SearchEmployee controller, Index action). But the idea is to keep the address http://localhost/find-the-best-employees.

How can I make this work on ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

I was having a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752922/asp-mvc-redirect-without-changing-urlrouting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072925/how-do-i-301-redirect-home-to-root) with no luck during tests.

Comment: It is not only possible but it's also one of the great features of ASP.NET MVC. The fact that you can map your URLs to any controller/action (rather than having the URL dictate the class/file to render) is a great feature. The solution that @JOBG suggests looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Global.asax define a route like:

```cs
 routes.MapRoute(
                   "findEmployess",                                              // Route name
                   "find-the-best-employees",                           // URL with parameters
                   new { controller = "SearchEmployee", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
               );
```

For this to work you need to use the route-name when generating the url, using this html helper

```cs
<%: Html.RouteLink("Search Employees","findEmployess")%>
```

Also you need to define this route before the default route:

```cs
//Your custom routes goes HERE before the default route

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```